# How to echo filter used in filter_var

Tags: php, filter, echo, constants, predefined-variables

First I'll show the function:

```
function validate($data, $filter){
  if(!filter_var($data, $filter))
  { 
     return 'Filter used:'.$filter;
  }
  else
  {
     return 'good';
  }
}
```

When I use this function it will look like this:

```
$email = 'hello@hello.org';
echo validate($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Output is:

> Filter used: 274

The problem is that I want the output to be:

> Filter used: FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.

Answer (score 5):

To get the actual constant name you probably need to pass the filter as a string and use `constant()`:

```
function validate($data, $filter){
  if(!filter_var($data, constant($filter)))
  { 
     return 'Filter used:'.$filter;
  }
  else
  {
     return 'good';
  }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
echo validate($email, 'FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL');
```

I got to thinking about multiple flags, and I was bored.  This could get really messy but for simple filters it works:

```
function validate(){    
  $args = func_get_args();
  $data = array_shift($args);
  $con_args = array_map('constant', $args);
  array_unshift($con_args, $data);

  if(!call_user_func_array('filter_var', $con_args))
  { 
     return 'Filter used:'.implode(', ', $args);
  }
  else
  {
     return 'good';
  }
}

echo validate($url, 'FILTER_VALIDATE_URL', 'FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED');
```

Answer (score 1):

`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is a [named constant](http://php.net/define) that is set to `274`. Your `validate()` function never sees "FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL", it just sees `274` being passed into it and passes `274` to `filter_var()`, which knows how to handle it.

One advantage of constants for the developer is: by using an IDE with auto-complete and code intelligence, you can be certain of the variable's name and thus can avoid possible typos.

Look at @AbraCadaver's answer for an elegant solution to your query.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!